# Stanford NLP how to preprocessing the text

Tags: replace, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a sentence like this "The people working in @walman are not good"

I have a preprocessed text file which contains the mappings, similar to the following two lines:

```
@walman   Walman
@text     Test
```

For the above sentence I have to read through the text file and replace the word with any matching word found in the text file.

The above sentence will change to "The people working in Walman are not good"

I am looking for an API available in Standford NLP to read the input text file and replace the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only NLP-related part here is tokenization. You should read your text file into the map (e.g. `HashMap` in case of Java), then for each new sentence, you should tokenize it (e.g. by [Stanford tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml)), and check for each token if it is presented in the map; if yes, just replace by the found value from the map, if no, do nothing for this token.

Sample code for tokenization (taken from the link above):

```
  String arg = "The people working in @walman is not good";
  PTBTokenizer<CoreLabel> ptbt = new PTBTokenizer<CoreLabel>(new StringReader(arg),
          new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
  for (CoreLabel label; ptbt.hasNext(); ) {
    label = ptbt.next();
    System.out.println(label);
  }
}
```

So, `label.toString()` gives you the token without any suffixes.

Comment: Thanks nikitha.  When i do the tokenize and split the word while printing it is showing [The-1, people-2, working-3, in-4, @walman-5, is-6, not-7, good-8]. is there any way i can remove the word count in number. Any sample code is really aprreciated

Comment: Never mind i use the below code to make it working. for (CoreLabel token : document.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
         String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class); Any thoughts ?? . thanks for the help

Comment: I've added code example before yours, so you can choose)

Comment: thanks Nikitha. if i add two sentence like "The people working in @walman is not good.They are smart".it will get tokenize but  it consider one word as "good.They". If we put space between the . and the second word They  it looks good. Any thought

Comment: Stanford NLP, as many other tools, assumes the text to be spelled correctly, and absence of space before period is incorrect. 
So, the simplest solution is to add space after each period before tokenization, e.g. by 
arg= arg.replaceAll("\\.", ". ");